# How to retrieve the Category name, Category URL and Category image using Category-Id?

Tags: category, image, url

As we know that in the Category Management page we can upload an image and give a URL for each category. I want to retrieve the Category name, Category URL and Category image using only the Category Id that I already have with me. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ravi Chan,you can only do this Magento Category Model Call.

```
$Category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
$name=$Category->getName();
$url=$Category->getUrl();
$image=$Category->getImageUrl()
```

Comment: What about retrieving the image?

Comment: wait.....................

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(197, 167); ?>" />
```